Want to add two stages of $near geoSpatial query in mongoDB
I try to find all user that their start-location near to some lat,lng points and also their end-location near to some lat,lng points.
Already success find all users that start-location near to some lat,lng points because $near query run only for one stage.
Here is my user schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const pointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    required: true
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true
  }
});


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Name is required"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Email is required"],
    unique: true,

  
  startLoc: {
    type: pointSchema,
    required: true
  },
  endLoc: {
    type: pointSchema,
    required: true
  },
 
});

userSchema.index({ startLoc: '2dsphere' });
userSchema.index({ endLoc: '2dsphere' });

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;

And here also the query I already achieve
  const users = await User.find({
    startLoc: {
      $near: {
        $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [81.13498288424883, 53.8003659501793] },
        $minDistance: 1,
        $maxDistance: 500
      }
    }
  })

console.log(users)

